# Setting Up Windows Azure End To End Development Environment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2008r2-express, azure-appfabric

I downloaded AppFabric VS Tools and Tried To Install but it ends up with fatal Error.I have read n followed all the system requirements of exe, except the one with SQL Express point.I tried installing SQL Express 2008 r2 with default instance, but it takes Instance name as 'MSSQLSERVER',where as in link of system requirements it mentions that default instance name other than 'SQLEXPRESS' will fail. Please provide me step by step installation guides for AppFabric developer tools installation.

This is the download link and Informations : http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17691

I have VS 2010 n Windows 7 and SQL Server Express 2008 R2. Please provide information for Setting Up Complete(Hosting Web n WCF Applications,AppFabric Development,SQL Azure etc) Windows Azure Development Environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to install a CTP (Community Technology Preview, pre-release) of one specific part of Windows Azure, specifically AppFabric SDK for Service Bus and Caching. You shouldn't be starting with this.

Instead. go to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/) to install everything you need. You can also get to it by first visiting [www.azure.com](http://www.azure.com), hovering on the **Learn** tab, and selecting **Download SDK**. This is the simplest way to get everything you need installed.

Once everything's set up, you'll be ready to build everything you mentioned (WCF, AppFabric, SQL Azure). I'd advise grabbing the latest [Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8396), which has labs for everything you'd want to do. You can also get to this later by again going to [www.azure.com](http://www.azure.com), hovering over **Learn**, and selecting **Get Started**. You'll see a link on the right, under **Start a Tutorial**, for downloading the Platform Training Kit.

EDIT: You'll be able to take advantage of the local emulator to build most of the samples and develop your own projects. You'll need a Windows Azure subscription for Service Bus and Cache, as these aren't included in the emulator.

Hope that helps...